# Wrap external program in JavaFX 2.0 application

Tags: java, javafx-2, external-process

I Use Java SE 7 and try to build a demo application to learn new JavaFX 2.

I want to implement a "platform indepent" (unix / windows) ssh connection manager.
I dont really want to implement a ssh client like putty or the terminal under linux/unix systems like ubuntu.

I want to use those programs and want to include it in my java application.

One use case could be, the create tabs for multiple connections.

Is there a way to include them and control e.g. the focus, the position etc...?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue - thinking  about doing the same -> putty in javafx